# What is the error rate for random guessing?

Tags: error-handling

I am studying for my Machine Learning exam. In sample exam questions, there is a specific one that I could not understand:

[image: dataset]

And the question is: "What is the error rate for random guessing?"

I could not understand the question, can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random guessing of value of whcih column? For example random guessing the gender of each row is: `probability of it is male but guess female + vice versa` which is $\frac{7}{10}\times\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{10}\times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$ and it means the error of random guessing the value of `Gender` is $50\%$.
Also you can compute for the others by the possible value for each column. For example for the `Hair Length` the error would be $\frac{2}{3}$ or $66.66\%$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it was for "Gender" column. But I understand it now. Thanks a lot